# How to send an email to an Organic Group admin for every comment of their group?

Tags: rules, organic-groups

Drupal 7.x
Organic Groups / Rules 7.x-2.9

What is the best method to send an email to the 'Administrator Member' role of a group every time a comment is posted in their group?

I am looking to specify the exact groups that this rule works for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a rule with:

- Add Event "After saving new comment" or "after udating an existing comment"
- Add action to the rule, under the "Organic Groups" section, there is a "Get group managers from group audience".
- Then you add a loop for this list, and then use the "Send email" from under "System" section.